# Find lines by length in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is there's a way to bookmark all lines that are over a certain length in Notepad++?

For example, I'm trying to bookmark all lines that have over 15 characters.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: what is this about programming?

Comment: Questions about programming tools qualify as valid SO questions, and notepad++ is a code editor.

Comment: Agreed, came here for zero-padding a CSV file of ZIP codes.

Comment: Plain old notepad can be a code editor even

Answer (score 47):

There is an easy way to perform this.

1. Go to **Search** > **Find**... > Select the **Mark** Tab. Make sure you have Regular expression checked under the Search Mode box and make sure you check the **Bookmark Line** box.
2. You want to search for the following, still being under the **Mark** tab.

   ```
   Find what: ^.{15,}
   ```
3. Finally, click **Mark All** which bookmarks the lines that have `15` characters or more.

Example:

[image]

Comment: http://regexr.com/3am33

Comment: Great! And how can I show only this bookmarked lines?

Comment: I found it: Press CTRL-0 (Ctrl-Zero) to jump to the first marked line.

Comment: You can also do Search --> Bookmark --> Remove Unmarked Lines to view only the lines that you marked

Answer (score 12):

You mean something like this?

`.{15}`

Or mark all the lines, if longer than 15 characters:

`.{15,}`

[image]